# Tracking non-editable files in git

Tags: git

Lets say I have 3 pdfs each detailing the tasks I need to do. To do work as listed on each pdf, I create a branch for each. I track each pdf in each of the corresponding branch. (When i switch to branch-1, it shows me 1.pdf only and so on). I wouldn't have mixed feeling if this was a text file of instructions instead of a pdf. Is it a good practice to track files that are not text-editable? Should I do anything differently?

Comment: This is completely a preference/internal outlook. It is up to you or your company if it's "right" to track pdf files within your git repository. For instance some companies track image files which aren't text-editable but it makes sense for them. If tracking pdf files is a benefit to your project(easily communication, history tracking, etc.) then it is fine. Also just because it's not text-editable doesn't mean some one can't for instance update the pdf locally with a pdf tool and push those changes back up. Just depends.

Comment: Just keep in mind, git was designed for text files so it strengths lay there. It will track your binary files but merging and diff-ing will become very hard(if you need this features).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/17772048/6309